# Codeigniter $this->load->view to a Particular Section of page (Data-Toggle - Tab)

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have this admin panel where I use different data-toggle tabs.

In CI(3), if I go with `redirect('user/dashboard#new');` , it redirects me to correct section of view but not with form_validation errors.

And if I try `$this->dashboard('user/dashboard#new');` it renders the errors but leads me to the wrong section of page (not at #new).

I have just started developing with CI and looking for some help from seniors.

Thanks in advance.

Controller (user)

```
public function dashboard() {
if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')){
$data['homepage'] = '../../templates/vacations/users/dashboard';
$this->load->view('template_users',$data);
}else{
$data['session_error']='Either the session has expired or you have tried to access this page directly';
$this->load->view('../../templates/vacations/headfoot/header-login');
$this->load->view('../../templates/vacations/users/session-error', $data);
$this->load->view('../../templates/vacations/headfoot/footer-login');
}}
```

Form Validation

```
if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{
$this->dashboard('user/dashboard#new');
} else {
$this->load->model('model_users');
if($query = $this->model_users->insert_property_details())
{
redirect('user/dashboard#new'); 
} else {
redirect('user/dashboard#new');
}}}
```

Comment: Do you mean form_validation errors? And can you show your dashboard method code and code for the method that contains `redirect('user/dashboard#new');`?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have just added the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$this->dashboard('user/dashboard#new');` just runs/calls the method within the current page. `'user/dashboard#new'` does nothing because the method is not written to accept arguments anyway:

```
public function dashboard(/* arguments would be here normally */) { ... }
```

Redirecting right after running validation won't work because you will lose the validation errors when you load a new page.

You need to save the errors somewhere, such as to session data, then redirect to dashboard, and then load the errors from saved location and display them on the dashboard view.

Here's an example using session data.

Form method:

```
if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{
    $this->session->set_userdata('validation_errors', validation_errors());
    $this->session->mark_as_flash('validation_errors'); // data will automatically delete themselves after redirect
    redirect('user/dashboard#new');
}
else { ... }
```

Dashboard method:

```
public function dashboard() 
{
    if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')){
        $data['validation_errors'] = $this->session->userdata('validation_errors');
        $data['homepage'] = '../../templates/vacations/users/dashboard';
        $this->load->view('template_users',$data);
    } else { ... }
}
```

Getting error array from form validation class (for comments below):

```
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {
    public function error_array()
    {
        return $this->_error_array;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for quick solution. I have just added
<?php echo $validation_errors; ?>
to view file and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Just one thing.All these error shows at one place all together. Can I break them to form's field value and display them in front of each field in view file?

Comment: Extend the Form Validation class to add a method to return the array that it already uses (it's a protected variable by default). I added an example above. Then you can use `$this->form_validation->error_array()` instead of `validation_errors()` to get the array.